# Create a VectorSource inside a getLocation() function

Tags: javascript, angular, api, openlayers

I'm programming a map with [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) (4.6.5) and [Angular](https://angular.io/) (6). I'm using a french [API](https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api) that returns GeoJSON files at the end of a request like this :

`https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=2.37&lat=48.357`.

I want to use the same principle with user location. In order to perform the request I'm using the HTTP protocol. I have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxqjux) to illustrate my work.

I'm able to recover user location and build the request with latitude and longitude. But I cannot use the URL in a VectorSource to place a point corresponding to the location.

I have three errors : `Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined`, `ERROR CONTEXT` and `rbush_1.default is not a function`

Comment: Why can't you use "the URL in a VectorSource to place a point corresponding to the location"?

Comment: I have errors when I try to place the marker on the map using the generated GeoJSON file. I have three errors : `Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined`, `ERROR CONTEXT` and `rbush_1.default is not a function`

Comment: @Adrien Please edit this info in the question.

Comment: @NicoHaase I'll do it !

Comment: Try to inspect this dedicated sample without Angular https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/5ed495566330c3da685110ecad5c467b as you don't need to create each time a source and a layer. Create it one time and then populate/clear with features from your JSON returned by the API endpoint.

Comment: @ThomasGratier where is he `creat[ing] each time a source and a layer` ? I'm only seeing it once in his code

Comment: Thank you @ThomasGratier for your help !

Comment: @trichetriche Each time the geolocation is updated, he creates a new layer & source

Comment: `watchPosition` monitors position changes, `getCurrentPosition` should call the callback only once ?

Comment: Pour moi, l'erreur semble être dans `this.map.addControl(this.vectorLayer_location);` Tu cherches à ajouter un control alors que 1. `vectorLayer_location` est une couche donc cela devrait être `this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer_location);` 2. Si tu fais ce remplacement, tu cherches à ajouter la couche alors qu'elle n'est pas encore créée (seulement quand `getLocation` est appelé PS: j'ai survolé donc semi-affirmatif sur point 2...

Comment: J'ai essayé `this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer_location);` mais ça génère encore plus d'erreurs et la carte ne s'affiche plus. C'est ce qui expliquerait le bug ? J'essaie d'ajouter une couche qui n'existe pas encore ? L'erreur `setMap` ?

Comment: Oui, si tu regardes mon code exemple,  tu devrais créer `this.vectorLayer_location = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector()
});
map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer_location);` dans ton `ngOnInit`

Comment: J'ai mis à jour le [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxqjux) ! Est-ce que c'est bien ce que tu penses ?

Comment: J'ai fait des modifs dans https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pk6pn1 et là, pas d'idée. Il me reste comme erreur ERROR CONTEXT et rbush_1.default is not a function. Je pense que là tu peux ouvrir une issue sur Openlayers pour un problème de bundling/scope (les autres erreurs, c'était lié à ton usage de `addControl`

Comment: Ok merci @ThomasGratier je vais faire ça !

Comment: PS: RBush est un lib qui fait gère des index spatiaux en JS. Potentiellement, cela peut venir aussi de TypeScript s'il ne le gère pas bien mais là c'est une hypothèse "tiré par les cheveux" (Petit utilisateur Typescript et incompétent en Angular)

Comment: Oui je pense mais bon on peut se permettre de chercher assez loin étant donné le problème de caractère insolvable ...

Comment: Une démo qui marche en partant "from scratch" https://github.com/ThomasG77/myangular-openlayers-app Le seul truc non implémenté est le bouton d'activation/désactivation de la géolocation (je suis expert Openlayers pas Angular...)

Comment: Super j'ai testé et ça fonctionne ! Le problème venait effectivement de mon code je vais l'approfondir pour savoir ce qui n'allait pas ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make 2 HTTP calls with `callApi` : the object returned is a `Subscription`.

In the first case, you `subscribe` to it : everything is good there.

In your second call, you use it as a string for an URL : **that's your issue**.

Consider using directly the URL such as :

```
url: `https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/reverse/?lon=${longitude}&lat=${latitude}`
```

Comment: So, the `callApi` function is useless ? I have updated my Stackblitz but that didn't work anymore ... Maybe I didn't understand ?

Comment: Bon, on est tous les deux français, l'objectif étant de t'aider, on va continuer en français et je modifierai ma réponse à la fin. L'appel HTTP est pas inutile, il est juste mal utilisé. Le mieux, ça serait de me dire ce que tu comptes faire, que je puisses le reproduire et te dire ce qui cloche !

Comment: En gros je récupère le fichier GeoJSON que j'ai généré avec l'API ça j'y arrive mais le problème c'est que je veux, grâce à VectorSource, stocker la position de mon marqueur et le placer sur ma carte. Ce pourquoi j'ai placé `locationLayer` dans `getLocation()` parce que pour l'instant le marqueur ne s'affiche pas sur la carte malgré que j'ai récupéré le fichier GeoJSON

Comment: Ok je vois, j'ai regardé tes erreurs console, ce sont des erreurs d'OpenLayers, tu dois mal l'importer. Décommente ton `callApi` pour corriger la première erreur, et essaie de bien suivre le getting started d'openLayer. Une fois que tu n'as plus d'erreurs, vérifie que tout fonctionne bien, moi en attendant je vais chercher comment poser des marqueurs sur la carte

Comment: D'après Stackblitz il y a des erreurs d'importation mais mon projet existe sur mon oridnateur avec des fonds de cartes privés et les imports sont bons. Le souci c'est que setMap pointe sur rien ... J'ai déjà utilisé OpenLayers pour placer des marqueurs sur une carte grâce à des fichiers GeoJSON et ça a fonctionné, je cherche donc à l'adapter dans le cas d'une URL qui n'est pas fixe

Comment: Ok si ça marche sur ton poste je vais me concentrer sur le fait que l'URL n'est pas fixe, et tu testeras en local. Elle est censée changer suivant quoi l'URL ? Juste latitude et longitude ? Ou bien elle dépend d'autre chose ?

Comment: Ok merci. Oui juste en fonction de la longitude et latitude récupérée à partir de la localisation du client.

Comment: Bah normalement le code que je t'ai donné devrait fonctionner (à supposer que tu as correctement écrit l'URL et les paramètres à la fin de l'URL). Tu rencontres une autre erreur en local ?

Comment: Pour l'instant le code Stackblitz et local est le même. En local ça ne fonctionne pas plus et voici les erreurs : `Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined` et `ERROR CONTEXT`. Il est fort possible que je n'ai pas bien compris les modifications à effectuer, le code Stackblitz est peut être faux

Comment: Donc c'est toujours une erreur d'import : `Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined at _ol_Map_.eval (angular-nxqjux.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/ol@4.6.5/pluggablemap.js:255)`. Il faut que tu importes et déclare ta librairie correctement, pour le moment ton code est pas en cause, uniquement ta dépendance

Comment: C'est bizarre puisque jusque là je n'avais pas d'erreurs d'imports alors que j'utilise juste en plus le protocole HTTP ... Mais du coup ça ne pose pas de problème qu'on appelle deux fois la même URL ?

Comment: Erreur d'import = pas une erreur de ton code. Là c'est bien dit dans la stack trace, l'erreur provient de la librairie. Après c'st peut-être que tu as oublié de déclarer une variable nécessaire ! Je connais pas spécialement OpenLayer, mais ça ressemble à une erreur de type "j'ai oublié d'attacher la carte à un élément HTML"

Comment: J'ai essayé d'importer pluggablemap aussi mais ça ne change rien ... En effet le problème a l'air de venir d'OpenLayers mais je ne vois vraiment pas d'où puisque j'utilise le même principe qui fonctionnait aussi avec Angular pour les URL statiques

Comment: Et t'as pas oublié une ligne de code ? Je sais qu'avec leaflet on doit l'affecter à un élément comme ça : `this.leafletMap = L.map(this.map.nativeElement).setView(x, 6);`. Toi, ça doit être équivalent, mais `setView` devient `setMap` ?

Comment: Non la carte se met toute seule en place sans avoir besoin de 'appeler c'est juste grâce a `this.map.addControl(this.vectorLayer_location);` que les marqueurs devraient se placer ...

Comment: Ok j'ai regardé, l'erreur provient de `this.locationLayer = new VectorSource({
            url: '...',
            format: new GeoJSON()
          });`. Peut-être que tu le déclares mal ?

Comment: Je vais en pause et après je regarde, merci !

Comment: Je ne vois aucune erreur dans la ligne que tu m'indiques, c'est exactement comme dans mon code précédent qui lui fonctionne. Ne serait-il pas mal placé ?

Comment: J'ai pas dit qu'il y avait une erreur dans ta ligne, mais que la ligne était en erreur : si tu la supprimes, l'erreur disparaît. C'est exactement ce que je te disais, que c'est la librairie qui est en défaut. J'ai cherché vite faite sur Internet mais j'ai pas trouvé de sujet qui remonte les mêmes erreurs ... Tu es obligé d'utilisé OpenLayers ou tu peux changer à tout moment ?

Comment: Malheureusement je dois garder OpenLayers ... Regarde la réponse de Thomas Gratier (en commentaire de mon post) il y a peut-être la solution je regarde aussi, son code fonctionne mais avec Angular je vais sûrement devoir effectuer des modifications et retomber dans le même problème ...

Comment: Oui son code fonctionne mais comme tu dis, c'est pas un contexte Angular. Il a l'air d'avoir utilisé le même à quelques détails près, essaie peu-être d'implémenter la gestion d'erreurs, vois si ça corrige les erreurs qui popent, sinon honnêtement je vois pas du tout ... Vois si tu peux pas ouvrir une issue sur le git OpenLayers, ils auront sans doute plus de réponses que sur SOF !

Comment: Ne pose pas la question sur le dépôt car ils vont fermer ta question (la règle est de poser les questions d'usage uniquement sur StackOverflow...) Le serpent qui se mord la queue

Comment: Donc le seul moyen d'avoir une réponse est sur SOF, où personne ne semble pouvoir apporter une réponse ? pratique ...